# Proof that if expectation of an operator is zero for all vectors, then the operator itself must be zero

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, vectors

I was attending a Quantum Mechanics lecture when the instructor casually mentioned the following theorem:

> $\langle \alpha \rvert A \rvert \alpha \rangle = 0 ~\forall \alpha \implies A=0$, where $A$ is an operator and $\rvert\alpha\rangle$ is an arbitrary ket in the complex Hilbert space.

I have always assumed that the above theorem was 'obvious', but on second thought, it doesn't seem to be easy or trivial to prove. I tried looking at various sources for the theorem, but it seems to be surprisingly difficult to find this theorem or proof anywhere.

I would be very glad if someone would point me towards the proof of the theorem, and provide a small outline of it if possible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm

Comment: @CountIblis OP did not say $A$ needs to be bounded.

Comment: @CountIblis $\langle \alpha \vert A \lvert \alpha \rangle$ is not the norm of $A$ - that would be $\langle \alpha \vert A^\dagger A \vert \alpha \rangle$.

Comment: your "theorem" needs extra assumptions. It is not valid in this general form.

Comment: For example: if you consider the harmonic oscillator problem, its Fock space and the usual orthonormal basis, then the property you are describing is shared by the creation-anihillation operators: $\langle n \rvert \alpha \rvert n \rangle=\langle n \rvert \alpha^\dagger \rvert n \rangle=0$ $\forall n$. But these are certainly not equal to zero!

Comment: @QCrypt The property described is supposed to hold for *all* vectors, not only for a basis. The c/a operators do not fulfill this for all operators, e.g. $\langle \alpha \vert a \vert \alpha \rangle$ is non-zero for $\lvert \alpha\rangle = \lvert 0\rangle + \lvert 1 \rangle$, so they are not a counterexample.

Comment: mmm yes you are right here. I was confused by the other discussion and thought OP was speaking for basis vectors. However, i still feel there are missing assumptions here (at the OP).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pick any orthonormal basis $\lvert \psi_i\rangle$ of our Hilbert space. Then $\langle \psi_i\vert A \vert \psi_i \rangle = 0$ for all $i$ by assumption, and for $\lvert \phi_{ij}(a,b)\rangle := a\lvert \psi_i\rangle + b\lvert \psi_j\rangle$ we find
$$ \langle \phi_{ij} \vert A \vert \phi_{ij}\rangle = a^\ast b \langle \psi_i \vert A \vert \psi_j\rangle + ab^\ast \langle \psi_j \vert A \vert \psi_i\rangle = 0,$$
which for $a,b = 1$ implies
$$ \langle \psi_i \vert A \vert \psi_j \rangle = - (\langle \psi_j \vert A \vert \psi_i\rangle )^\dagger = - \langle \psi_i \vert A^\dagger \vert \psi_j \rangle $$
which means that $A = -A^\dagger$, i.e. $A$ is anti-Hermitian. Since anti-Hermitian operators are in particular normal, they are diagonalizable by the spectral theorem, and therefore $\langle \alpha \vert A \vert \alpha\rangle  = 0$ means that all eigenvalues are 0, i.e. the diagonalization of $A$ is the zero matrix, which also means $A = 0$.

Note that the application of the spectral theorem relies on the space being a complex vector space, and that the assertion would be false over a real vector space - $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is a counterexample on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (but not on $\mathbb{C}^2$, since its expectations values do not vanish for all vectors there).

Comment: Why $\langle \psi_i \vert A \vert \psi_j \rangle = - \langle \psi_i \vert A^\dagger \vert \psi_j \rangle$ implies that $A = -A^\dagger$ ?

Comment: @QCrypt If $\langle \psi_i \vert A \vert \psi_j\rangle = \langle \psi_i \vert B \rvert \psi_j\rangle$ for all $i,j$ in a basis $\psi$, then $A=B$. In other words, operators whose matrix elements are the same are the same operators.

Comment: But isn't this what the OP is all about ?

Comment: @QCrypt No, at least not how I read it. Note that in the OP, there is the *same* vector on both sides, while here $\psi_i$ and $\psi_j$ are different.

Comment: This proof implicitly requires $A^*$ to be defined everywhere. This is equivalent to $A$ being closed. Since $A$ is defined everywhere (implicit from OP), the closed graph theorem implies $A$ must be bounded. So this proof requires the additional hypothesis that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Well, generally $\langle \psi_i \vert A \vert \psi_j\rangle = \langle \psi_i \vert B \rvert \psi_j\rangle$ for all $i,j$ in some basis $\psi$, implies that $A-B$ is contained in the kernel of the specific representation (and thus its action is zero). Not that it is necessarilly equal to $0$ (as an abstract operator). But maybe this is enough for the OP's meaning.

Comment: @QCrypt Sorry, kernel of what representation? There is no difference between the "action" of an operator on the vectors and the operator - if it "acts" as zero on all basis vectors (and hence all vectors by linearity), then it *is* the zero operator.

Comment: I mean the matrix representation of the operator.

Comment: No, generally the action of an operator on a specific space and the operator itself are not the same thing. (For example, consider an operator $A$ acting on a space and consider all those vectors $v$ for which $Av=0$. Then the matrix representation of $A$ on the subspace generated by those vectors is zero, however $A$ itself is not, since it acts non-trivially on the whole of the space).

Comment: @QCrypt I'm not looking at a subspace here, the $\psi_i$ are a basis for the entire space (it wouldn't be a basis if it only spanned a subspace!). I'm a bit confused about what exactly the issue is.

Comment: @QCrypt $\langle n \vert a \vert m \rangle = \sqrt{m}\langle n \vert m - 1\rangle = \sqrt{m} \delta_{n,m-1}$, but $- \langle n \vert a^\dagger \vert m \rangle = \sqrt{m + 1}\langle n \vert m + 1 \rangle = \sqrt{m + 1} \delta_{n,m+1}$. These do not look equal to me.

Comment: yes you are right on that. I was misleaded by my previous comment on the OP (which was not correct). However, i still find your argument not convincing. (Meaning that equal matrix elements do not imply that the operators are identified in general). Maybe i will try to come back later on this point with some (counter)example.

Comment: @QCrypt Mr. ACuriousMind is assuming $A$ is a continuous operator and is correct in that context. If you are talking about discontinuous operators, then you are of course correct.

Answer (score 3):

1) Let us consider any $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$.

We have:
$$
\langle u|A|u\rangle=0,~~~\langle v|A|v\rangle=0.
$$

Let us consider $|u\rangle+|v\rangle$:
$$
(\langle u|+\langle v|)A(|u\rangle+|v\rangle)=0,
\\
0=(\langle u|+\langle v|)A(|u\rangle+|v\rangle)=\langle u|A|u\rangle+\langle u|A|v\rangle+\langle v|A|u\rangle+\langle v|A|v\rangle=\langle u|A|v\rangle+\langle v|A|u\rangle
$$
Thus we get:
$$
\langle u|A|v\rangle=-\langle v|A|u\rangle.
$$

Similarly, we consider $|u\rangle+i|v\rangle$:
$$
0=(\langle u|-i\langle v|)A(|u\rangle+i|v\rangle)=\langle u|A|u\rangle+i\langle u|A|v\rangle-i\langle v|A|u\rangle+\langle v|A|v\rangle=i\langle u|A|v\rangle-i\langle v|A|u\rangle.
$$
Consequently,
$$
i\langle u|A|v\rangle=i\langle v|A|u\rangle,
\\
\langle u|A|v\rangle=\langle v|A|u\rangle.
$$

From
$$
\langle u|A|v\rangle=-\langle v|A|u\rangle,~~~\langle u|A|v\rangle=\langle v|A|u\rangle,
$$
we get
$$
\langle u|A|v\rangle=0=\langle v|A|u\rangle
$$
for any $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$.

2) Let us consider any $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle=A|u\rangle$.
$$
0=\langle v|A|u\rangle=\langle v|v\rangle.
$$
This is possible if and only if $|v\rangle=0$.

For any $|u\rangle$ we get:

$$
A|u\rangle=0.
$$

And this is the definition of $A=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late on this, the correct mathematical theorem (in the sense implied by @Ryan Unger in the comments) states:

> **Theorem**: If $A:D(A)\subsetneq \mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{R}(A)\subset\mathcal{H}$ is a linear operator in a complex separable Hilbert space, then we have the following equivalence:
> $$ \forall \psi\in D(A), \langle \psi,A\psi\rangle =0 \Rightarrow A\equiv \hat{0}_{\mathcal{H}} \Leftrightarrow D(A)\text{ is dense everywhere in } \mathcal{H} $$

> **Ideas for a proof**: The vanishing of the expectation values of the domain means that $\left(D(A)\right)^{\perp}= 0$. We actually have that $\overline{D(A)}^{\perp} = 0$, because one can show that $\left(D(A)\right)^{\perp}=\overline{D(A)}^{\perp}$ by continuity of the scalar product, therefore $\overline{D(A)}=\mathcal{H}$, in other words $A$ is densely defined.

As stated, the result in the quote from the OP is valid for operators defined everywhere on the Hilbert space and is nothing but the trivial assertion that follows from $\mathcal{H}^\perp = 0$, namely that $\mathcal{R}(A)=0\Leftrightarrow A \equiv 0$.

Answer (score -1):

I will give a semi mathematical point of view, and a completely intuitive point of view.

**Mathematical(ish) POV**

We have $$\langle \alpha |A|\alpha\rangle = 0 \  \ \forall |\alpha\rangle$$

Switching to the matrix view of operators we can say

$$A = \sum \limits_{i,j} a_{ij} |a_i\rangle\langle a_j|$$

Thus
$$|a_n|^2 ||\langle \alpha|a_n\rangle||^2 = 0 $$

Besides the trivial case the inner product will not be 0, but we also have the condition from the axioms of QM that $|a_n|^2 \geq 0 $. Thus the only way for this to be true for an arbitrary $|\alpha\rangle$ is for the coefficients to be $0$ which is equivalent to saying $A = 0$.

(Another way of seeing this is since $|\alpha \rangle$ is arbitrary, choose it to be one of the eigenvectors, $|a_n\rangle$. Each time you do this the only solution is that the coefficient is 0. Repeat $\forall n$ and you'll see that $A$ must be the $0$ operator.

Comment: In your second equation - don't we first have to prove that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: I don't think so. The matrix view just requires any linearly dependent set of vectors that span the space. Although, the fact that A is hermitian by the postulates of QM guarantees that it is diagonilizable.

Comment: If $A$ were not diagonalizable, then we could not write it that way :) I was being nice but you do have to show this first. Otherwise in general we can only write $A = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij} |a_i \rangle |a_j \rangle \langle a_i | \langle a_j|$.

Comment: It depends on the level which you're attacking it from. From an undergrad physics perspective my answer was sufficient. The postulates of QM guarantee the diagonaliszability, and often it is simply stated that you can do this.

Comment: Oh apologies. I just realised it says it's summed over n. When it should be a double index. I don't think your equation is right. I'm not satisfied with my answer but I'lld edit it when I get a chance.

Comment: That is not true, the postulates don't guarantee the diagonalizability of operators you see in undergrad. One example is the creation and annihiliation operators which aren't diagonalizable. The $A$ in your answer is mostly correct now but the $|a_i \rangle$ should read $|a_i a_j \rangle$. The rest of the answer needs that $A$ is written as you previously wrote it though, so you'd have to show it is diagonalizable first. The last sentence you wrote is also not true, it shows that the diagonal elements are 0 in any basis but it doesn't follow obviously from this that the operator is 0.